# Difference between "Security Configuration Manager" and "Security Configuration Wizard"

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2008-r2, configuration

I want some clarifications about differences between SCW and SCM.
strictly Speaking when I use SCM baseline for specific Server Role (domain controller, ftp server, ...), I get for example 200 gpo's and when I use scw for same server role, I get 300 gpo's. And between these gpo's there are very little similarity (after comparing these two gpo's).

Is not this a contradiction? if no, what is the justification?

Thanks in advance...